# 404 when clicking 'messages' link in Careers header

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, 404-not-found

I get a 404 error message when visiting this link:  http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/messages  (this is where the "messages" link at the top of the page takes me)

When I view my profile, then click the messages link on the right side of the page, I am correctly taken to my messages.

I don't have an employer account, but I do have a CV/profile on careers.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: bad link]

Comment: On which page do you see a link to that URL? I can't find it anywhere. Logged in as a job seeker, the 404 is certainly by design on that target page, but it's a bug if the link is showing up at all.

Comment: @Jon I added a screenshot to show which link I'm talking about.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache completely? The link doesn't appear on that page when I'm logged in. Have you ever had an employer account, and/or have you ever received a message through careers?

Comment: I have received messages through careers before, and when I click the "my profile" button, then click the "messages" link halfway down the right side of the page, I can see my inbox correctly.  I do not, nor have ever had, an employer account.  I was a paid subscriber to careers 1.0, if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the report.  Fixed in source, will be deployed shortly.

Comment: Thanks!  The link takes me to my messages now.

Comment: What was the issue? I don't have that link on my page. I'm assuming it's because I've never received any messages on there?

Comment: @Jon, the link now goes to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/messages, so I assume it was just pointing to the wrong page?

Comment: @Jon @ktrauberman: We don't show the link if you've never gotten any messages.  Before this fix we were finding ktrauberman's messages and pointing him to the employer messages page instead of the candidate messages page.